# Difference between past simple and past perfect in conditional tenses

Tags: difference, conditional-constructions, past-perfect, past-simple

I have been confused about the difference between simple and past perfect in conditional tenses.

```
     “If we had looked at the map, we wouldn’t be lost.”
     “If we looked at the map, we wouldn’t be lost.”

     “If you had studied harder, you would have passed the exam.”
     “If you studied harder, you would have passed the exam.”
```

If you know which one is correct in the first and second examples please tell me. Also, tell me why the another one is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is correct in both cases. They describe an alternative reality for something which has already happened (we are lost - you failed the exam).

Using the past simple in a conditional, we get:

*If we looked at the map [now], we might be able to work out where we are.*

*If you studied harder, you would have a better chance of passing the exam.* [the exam hasn't happened yet.]